# Actualizar un Git a través de otro por consola

Tags: laravel, git, github

Espero poder explicarme. Estoy trabajando con 2 sistemas en Laravel, cada uno con su github. Son similares pero no idénticos.

Tengo ciertas carpetas que son iguales y otras que no, por ejemplo la carpeta view/mails son distintas, la carpeta config es distinta, pero la carpeta view, la carpeta app, observer etc son idénticas, y por ello quisiera poder actualizar ambos git desde uno.

Es decir, supongamos que estoy trabajando sobre el proyecto A, desde consola actualizo el repositorio con git push origin master, esto me actualizará un solo repositorio que es el del proyecto A.

La pregunta es, como puedo por consola o por algún otro método que determinados archivos se actualizen en ambos repositorios o al revés que determinadas carpetas NO se actualizen en ambos repositorios pero el resto SI.

Se logra comprender?

Porque si los mantengo separados, por ejemplo si modifico un controller del proyecto A luego tengo que ir al proyecto B y hacer lo mismo para actualizar sus repositorios pero si modifico un mail del proyecto A NO QUIERO que se actualize en el proyecto B, se entiende?

Comment: no no se entiende

Comment: Quizás con algo de submodulos git puedas resolver tu reto. Si quieres, revisa esta documentación: https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Las-herramientas-de-Git-Subm%C3%B3dulos Sería genial que si te funciona, compartieras el procedimiento que utilizaste y los resultados.

Comment: podrías proporcionar un árbol de carpetas del proyecto con el comando 'tree' ? marcando con asteriscos las carpetas "compartidas"

Comment: ¿Estarías dispuesto a usar otro IDE? Tanto [tag:intellij-idea], como [tag:eclipse] y me parece que [tag:netbeans] manejan los patchfiles.

Answer (score 0):

**Recomendaría en este caso dos soluciones:**

> Solución 1

- Que el mismo repositorio sea utilizado para tus 2 Apps pero en diferentes [ramas git](https://gist.github.com/aaossa/7db152babead60ab097ba2c898d379a6)

> Solución 2  **Posiblemente la mejor solución por ser mas facil de manejar y escalar**

- Las 2 Apps en repositorios diferentes y las carpetas compartidas sería un tercer repositorio que los proyectos base compartirian.

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus respuestas, las estudiaré y vere cual implemento,  GRACIAS !!!!

Comment: ¿Solucionó tu problema, @desarrollosTELLO? Por favor no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada si tu problema se solucionó. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde y te dará 2 puntos de reputación). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!